# Access class static variable from super class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a couple of 'Child' classes which are quite similar and thus wanted to group common methods in a parent class. My problem comes when trying to access static variables of the child classes from the super class.

The following code throws the error:  `NameError: name 'var' is not defined`

```
class Parent:
    @staticmethod
    def do_something_with_var():
        print(var)

class Child(Parent):
    var = "Hello world"

Child.do_something_with_var()
```

Next thing I tried was obviously to declare `var` in `Parent`, but the same error persists.

```
class Parent:
    var = ""

    @staticmethod
    def do_something_with_var():
        print(var)

class Child(Parent):
    var = "Hello world"

Child.do_something_with_var()
```

A solution that I found was to receive the sender class, but then the call becomes a bit ugly:

```
class Parent:
    @staticmethod
    def do_something_with_var(cls):
        print(cls.var)

class Child(Parent):
    var = "Hello world"

Child.do_something_with_var(Child)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused over the usage of staticmethods(your third attempt), accessing class variables (second attempt).

What you want to do is `classmethods`, as shown under (Python 2.7):

```
class Parent(object):
    @classmethod
    def do_something_with_var(cls):
        print cls.var

class ChildA(Parent):
    var = "Child A"

ChildA.do_something_with_var()  # prints Child A
```

This example is equivalent to your third attempt.

Comment: Oh, I actually tried your solution but I was still providing Child as an argument... All clear now!

Answer (score 1):

Static scoping of the method means it is bound to the class scope as a namespace, without any reference to the class.

What you need is to have a [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), so that you are able to get a reference to the class.